# How to implement a custom loss function in Keras using results from current newwork?

Tags: keras

I am quite new to Keras, Could you please suggest me how to create a custom loss function for the following network?

```
x1  x2   x3   A
 \  /   /
  y1   /
   \  /
    y2
```

The output is y2 = f(x1, x2, x3).

I want to feed input A to the same network and use the output for the loss function as below.

Loss = y2  - f(A, x2, x3)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to train anything? What?

Comment: Hi @DanielMöller
I just want to train a network that can minimize the differences between using input = (x1,x2,x3) and input = (A, x2, x3).

Comment: That network will eventually get to the conclusion that all weights = 0 do the trick, no? Is this really the complete problem? Isn't there any additional architecture?

Comment: Thank you @DanielMöller, I just realized that my example will lead to all weights = 0. 

Actually, I'm trying to implement the loss function in the paper named "ReasoningWith Neural Tensor Networks
for Knowledge Base Completion" using keras.